# Make transparent header CSS

Tags: css, joomla, background

I have a problem with making header transparent. I have created an image and placed it in the header however there is white background behind it. How I can make this background it transparent or end it after slider?

CSS class: #zo2-header.zo2-sticky

Thank you!

Comment: IS that you want to apply for any specific image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being is that all elements are a child of `<section class="wrapper boxed container">` which contains the following:

```
body.boxed .wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This means that no matter what colour or transparency levels you set to your header, the background will **always** be white behind it.

You either need to:

1. Move the section with the id `zo2-header-top` outside of `<section class="wrapper boxed container">`
2. Remove the background colour that has been assigned to `body.boxed .wrapper`, add something like the following to your CSS file `.white { background: #FFF; }` tand then assigned `class="white"` to all sections apart from the header.

Answer (score 1):

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

that a will handle transparency, adjust the value as required.

Answer (score 1):

As I could see in your template.css line: 2433 there is a rule:

```
body.boxed .wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You have to remove it and add background-color only to the div that needs to have background.

Comment: You have to add a new rule to the content div for white background.